# modsecurity apache mod-security.conf missing

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, mod-security, apache-2.2

Greetings Serverfaultians. I'm not a server guy as you can see from my noob score of 1 point. But maybe those more versed can help me.

I'm using Ubuntu v13.10 32-bit Server and Apache2 v2.4.6 and I'm trying to set up and configure `modsecurity` and `modevasive` on an internet-exposed production/test server. I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-install-apache2-modsecurity-and-modevasive-ubuntu-1204-lts-server.

But at step 3:

Now add these rules to Apache2. Open a terminal window and enter:

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod-security.conf
```

This file does not exist. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the file doesn't exist then you need to contact the author of the tutorial and get them to fix it.

Comment: Try going back to step 1. Sounds like you skipped it.

Comment: Don't know if you guys are being facetious--I followed all the steps. Anyway I tried to comment on that blog, but am getting 404 errors. Nevertheless, I may have found the solution in another answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you're using Ubuntu 14.04. there are a couple of changes on that version. To add the rules you want, edit the following file instead:

```
sudo vi /etc/apache/mods-enabled/security2.conf
```

Comment: I'm using v13.10, but the solution is the same.

Comment: I believe the apache should be apache2!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). Strange place for a server question. Regardless, it may help others: [Trying to setup mod-security but mod-security.conf is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23147554/trying-to-setup-mod-security-but-mod-security-conf-is-missing)

The file is named `/etc/apache2/mods-available/security2.conf` and it is enabled by default after `modsecurity` install.

```
# make changes to security2.conf
a2dismod security2
a2enmod security2
service apache2 restart
```

Similarly, `modevasive` is now `/etc/apache2/mods-available/evasive.conf`.